# Sending notifications via email before a specific date is met?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, web

I have some dates in the database of some events. I am thinking of a way to notify the
user a day before that date. I have no Idea how to do that.
Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some form of automation:

An automated task that queries your data and takes an action is generally know as a worker.

There are many ways to create / mange workers.  The most common in the LAMP stack is it to use cron jobs to call scripts (possibly php in this case) scripts.

a quick goolgle on cron job how-to would be suggested.  but here is one site
to look at

[Cron For Newbies](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)